# serving large files like ebooks

Tags: google-app-engine

can Google App Engine be used to store and serve large files like audible books?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Google App Engine can be used to store and serve large files (up to 2 GB in size) of any type, including ebooks, using the [Blobstore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html).

Comment: But serving files is limited to 1mb for API call.

Comment: Serving files from the blobstore is different, you call `blobstoreService.serve()` and these requests are exempt from the 1MB serving limit. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Serving_a_Blob